# Can anyone show why the given code to calculate the value of sin(x) using Taylor series expansion not working properly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, output, trigonometry

this is the code I tried, it's not working properly and i don't know the issue

```
import math as m
def sinse(x,n):
    sume=0
    for i in range(n+1):
        sume+=(m.pow(-1,i)*m.pow(x,2*i+1)/m.factorial(2*i+1))
        return sume
n=int(input('Enter the value of n:'))
x=int(input('enter the value of X:'))
print(sinse(x,n))
```

If this is not the correct code, please add any other code in the answer

Comment: It's not indented properly, so it will raise an indentation error. Is that what you're asking about, or have you just pasted it badly?

Comment: The indentation of your code is broken. As the problem is certainly related to the indentation of your return statement, but we can't know for sure, it's not possible to answer your question for sure as it stands.

Comment: @luigigi : Don't fix the indentation in the question if that might be the reason for the error.

Comment: @Matthias yes. probably you are right.I didn't think of that.

Comment: The program runs and the broken indentation is because I didn't paste it correctly. My issue is that the output is not correct

Comment: It seems to produce the correct result once the indentation is fixed, despite your claims that indentation is not the issue. Also, asking for help with "it doesn't work" is not considered acceptable. You need to provide details, for example sample inputs and outputs that illustrate the problem.  For these reasons I'm going to vote to close the question as "typographical error/cannot reproduce".

Comment: It's as inefficient as it could be.  You should not have power or factorial inside the loop.  You've coded it literally by looking at the formula, but this is a bad way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

The line `return sume` breaks the for loop. I'm not sure about the accuracy of your formula, but I think unindenting that line by 1 (so it occurs after the for loop but inside the function) should make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Fixing the indentation gives the following:

```
import math as m
def sinse(x,n):
    sume=0
    for i in range(n+1):
        sume+=(m.pow(-1,i)*m.pow(x,2*i+1)/m.factorial(2*i+1))
    return sume
n=int(input('Enter the value of n:'))
x=int(input('enter the value of X:'))
print(sinse(x,n))
```

Comment: the indentation is not the issue, I just didn't paste it correctly. Th program runs but it is not giving the correct output

Comment: Then your formula is incorrect. Without knowing what the result you are looking for, it is very hard to debug!

Comment: Thats the thing, I have the correct formula but I actually don't know what the Taylor series is, so can anyone help me on that?

Comment: "Don't know what the Taylor series is" - Taylor series expansion for any function f(x) can be found in any calculus text.  It's an alternative way to write a function that has n continuous derivatives, like trig functions, exponential, etc.